# Mysql - Many tables to come up with only 1 table for Login purposes

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship

**Example tables:**

Employee, Customer and Contractor

***Contractor*** table works the same way as Employee and Customer but with some different field exclusive to that table

**Purpose:** 
To create a **User** table as the base for Logging-in.

Proposed **User** table

```
User_ID     password     User_Type          
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Employee1    123*89       Employee       
Employee2    0123         Employee        
Customer1    12378        Customer       
Customer2    1234         Customer       
Contractor1  45678        Contractor
```

---

**Employee** table:

```
ID          Firstname   Lastname   Address
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Employee1    Bon        Smith       123 North Street NY
Employee2    John       Doe         245 South Street NY
```

---

**Customer** table:

```
ID          Firstname   Lastname   Address
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Customer1    Ron        Price       123 North Street NY
Customer2    Peter      Doe         245 South Street NY
```

**Questions:**

- Is my **User** table correct?
- Should I put the Password field to every table (Employee, Customer and  Contractor) rather than placing it on User table?
- Is there any **BEST way** to implement the User table that you know?

---

**Clarification:** All I want to do is to put all the data ID from different tables(Employee, Customer and Contractor) to 1 table **User**.

Comment: Do not save passwords in db without hashing... try using salted password hashing.

Comment: No need to put password field on every table.  Just on the User table makes most sense if that's the table you will be using to check their credentials.  Also, consider using auto incremented Id's rather than strings to ensure unqiueness, general good coding practice and (in some cases) improve speed.

Comment: @NETCreatorHosting-WebDesign The password is encrypted. I;m just focusing on the table structure

Comment: @Raf I hope you mean "hashed" and not actually "encrypted", the difference being the former cannot be reversed while the latter can.

Comment: The PK could be (id , type)

Comment: Yes @Strawberry , already established that. See my brief Clarification added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion

**TABLE USER ROLE**

```
------------------------
ID   |    ROLENAME     |
 1   |    Employee
 2   |    Contractor   |
------------------------
```

**TABLE USERACCOUNT**

```
-------------------------------
ID USERNAME  PASSWORD USERROLE |
-------------------------------
1  employee1  password    1    |
2  Contractor password    2    |
--------------------------------
```

**TABLE EMPLOYEE**

```
--------------------------------------------
ID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME  ADDRESS  USERACCOUNT|
--------------------------------------------|
1   FName      Lname    address     1       |
2   fname      lname    address     2       |
--------------------------------------------
```

**TABLE CONTRACTOR**

```
--------------------------------------------
ID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME  ADDRESS  USERACCOUNT|
--------------------------------------------|
1   FName      Lname    address     1       |
2   fname      lname    address     2       |
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What format is the password saved and recommendations surrounding it

Comment: I'm just confuse a bit. Should I use the ID from USERACCOUNT or from USER to login?
Let say I'm using 2 required fields(ID and Password) to Login. I understand it has Username field but I want to know if I'll be using ID, what ID should it be?

Comment: @Raf  use id from useraccount

Comment: Please see my added Clarification.
Now I'm wondering how this works in the 3 tables (Employee, Customer and Contractor)?
It seems like your User table has all the fields from Employee, Customer and Contractor where they should be created separately. See my updated table samples.

Answer (score 0):

ya best practice for this is to create a login table separate as users

### User_ID        name       username          password          role

10             Ram1          ram12            123            Employee
11             Ram2          ram14            456            Employee
13             Ram3          ram15            789            Customer
14             Ram4          ram16            901            Customer
15             Ram4          ram17            110            Contractor

take the User_ID as primary key now store user Id to other table to make relation

Now in table account ::--

account_Id       user_Id    account_no        balance

1                  10          123               19999
2                  11          456               8723773
3                  13          272               238738
4                  14          2673              47437
5                  15          3737              36732

if you want data from both table then join both table that means inner join on
(user.user_id = account.user_id)

Comment: Why it has no balance? what is this for?

Comment: sorry the column is not arranged properly